# PostgreSQL security and passwords

Tags: postgresql, security, passwords

I'm having some issues with PostgreSQL security

I've taken the necessary steps

```
# ./psql -U postgres

# CREATE DATABASE devdb;

# CREATE USER devdb_user PASSWORD 'donttell';

# GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE devdb TO devdb_user;
```

However when I try to connect to the database with

```
# ./psql -d devdb -U devdb_user -W
```

It prompts me for the password as I would expect but any password I enter will still log me in. Why is this?

Comment: You meant `./psql -d devdb -U devdb_user -W` unstead `./psql -d devdb -U devdb_us -W` ?

Comment: yes, that was a typo, sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

Oh I see that in the pg_hba.conf it was reading the incoming connection as a local connection with had the trust authentication setting. Changed it to md5 and everything is all tightened up again